# how do i refrence ButtonTye=Image when using asp:Commandfield(need OnClientClick) Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Lets say i have

```
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product"
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Qty"
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
```

I want a popupp saying "Do you want to delete" when the users click the Show Delete button.
I know i have to pu my code in GridView1_RowDataBound.
But i do i get tot that button,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use ether jQuery ether code behind to add this warning message.

With code behind you can add an extra javascript call as

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // loop all data rows
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            // check all cells in one row
            foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
            {
                // I go to get the button if exist
                Button button = control as Button;
                if (button != null && button.CommandName == "delete")
                    // Add delete confirmation
                    button.OnClientClick = "return confirm("Delete this record? This action cannot be undone...");";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Direct using jQuery and javascript you can add this javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // make sure to select the correct buttons, here I say that value=Delete
    var oButtons = $('#<%= YourGridID.ClientID %> :button[value=Delete]');
    oButtons.each(function () {
        // capture here any other click event.
        var onclick = $(this).attr('onclick');
        $(this).attr('onclick', null).click(function () {                
            var doPostBack = confirm("Delete this record? This action cannot be undone...");
            if (doPostBack)
               return onclick();
            else
               return false
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: only some small modifications may need to make to locate the correct parameters of the buttons tha you like to capture.

Comment: Thanks but what i have is an image not a button <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image /> Cheers

Comment: This got me going.Thanks guys
int lastCellIndex = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1;
Button db = (Button)e.Row.Cells[lastCellIndex].Controls[0];
db.OnClientClick = "if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')) return false;";

Comment: @naijacoder do wait all from me, image also have onlick, if the image is inside anchor, cpature the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Use TeamplateField instead of CommandField and put into it button with CommandName="Delete". Then you can get this button by Id.

Comment: Thanks but what i have is an image not a button
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image />
Cheers